# Bar graph with editable dash table

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to make a bar graph with editable dash table but graph changes for just once time. After changing data in table, graph be updated but not like my expectation.

Below is my sample code:

```
from dash_table import DataTable
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go


raw_data = {'Type': ["Cash", "Credit Card"],
        'Rate': [50,50]}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
test_df['id'] = test_df['Type']
test_df.set_index('id', inplace=True, drop=False)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table',
        data=test_df.to_dict('records'),editable=True,
        columns=[
            {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True, "hideable": True}
            if i == "Type" or i == "Rate"
            else {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True}
            for i in test_df.columns
        ],
        style_cell={
            'minWidth': '0px',
            'maxWidth': '180px',
            'whiteSpace': 'no-wrap',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'textOverflow': 'ellipsis'},
        style_table={'overflowX': 'scroll'},
        row_deletable=True
    ),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='plot',
        style={"max-width": "600px",
               "margin": "auto",
               "display": "inline-block"})
])


@app.callback(Output('plot', 'figure'),
              [Input('table', 'data'),
              Input('table', 'columns')])

def update_graph(data, cols):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[c['name'] for c in cols])
    figure_2 = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(x=df['Type'],
           y=df['Rate'],
           width=0.45,
           text = df['Rate'],
           textposition='inside',
           marker_color='indianred')])
    return figure_2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=1211, debug=False)
```

My first time change, graph looking like this:
[image]

But from the second time, graph looking like this:
[image]

What should I do to fix this problem.
Actually I read `editable` docs but I still not get it. The Graph in docs is generated like this:

```
def display_output(rows, columns):
    return {
        'data': [{
            'type': 'heatmap',
            'z': [[row.get(c['id'], None) for c in columns] for row in rows],
            'x': [c['name'] for c in columns]
        }]
    }
```

I don't know how to apply it for bar graph.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a print statement inside your callback of `data` you will see on initial load the data is as expected

```
[{'Type': 'Cash', 'Rate': 50, 'id': 'Cash'}, {'Type': 'Credit Card', 'Rate': 50, 'id': 'Credit Card'}]
```

`Rate` holds a numeric value.

But when editing values in the datatable the value could be anything so dash table treats your input as a string and not a number.

So after editing a value in the `Rate` column `data` could now look like this

```
[{'Type': 'Cash', 'Rate': 50, 'id': 'Cash'}, {'Type': 'Credit Card', 'Rate': '200', 'id': 'Credit Card'}]
```

The value I filled in `200` is now a string in `data`.

It seems that when both `Rate` values are string values plotly doesn't know how it should draw the bars anymore.

What you could do is to convert the `Rate` column of `df` to numeric.

```
df['Rate'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Rate'])
```